# How do I combine a raster dataframe with a shapefile to create a map of species richness?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, raster, shapefile

I want to plot the raster plot/dataframe on top of the shapefile but I keep getting various errors depending on how I write the code.

I've tried using a + with the finished objects, landmap+critmapped, I've tried adding the codes together and plotting both as data but that didn't work:

I've tried the following, as well as other things...

Thank you for any help/direction.

```
critmapped<-ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = layer)) + 
geom_raster() +
scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "white") +
labs(fill = "Count") + 
theme_minimal() + ggplot() + geom_path(data = land_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = 'black', fill = 'green')

#Error: Don't know how to add ggplot() to a plot

critmapped+landmap2
#Error: Don't know how to add landmap2 to a plot

#The shapefile code

  require(rgdal)
  land <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/tjef631/Desktop/R Stats/Data/NE_10m_full", 
  layer = "ne_10m_land")
  land_df<-fortify(land)
  names(land_df)
  landmap<-ggplot() + geom_path(data = land_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group 
  = group),
            color = 'black', fill = 'green')
landmap


#the raster/dataframe code

  critmapped<-ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = layer)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "white") +
  labs(fill = "Count") + 
  theme_minimal()

  critmapped
```

Comment: You cannot have `ggplot() + ... + ggplot()`. Delete the second `ggplot`.

Comment: please provide a minimal self-contained example including data generated by code or from the R help examples.

Comment: If I remove the second ggplot it results in the error.. Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): fill = layer. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?

Comment: I'll get an example together